# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I'm trying to implement Facebook login button, but i'm receiving these errors when trying to run app:

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
Process: , PID: 4633
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:774)
    at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:825)
    at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$1.run(LoginButton.java:489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
com.android.vlada.sportisa E/GoogleApiAvailability: Google Play services is invalid. Cannot recover.
```

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private Button buttonRegistrujSe, buttonPrijaviSeKaoGost, buttonPrijavaRegistrovaniKorisnik;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private TextView info;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        buttonRegistrujSe = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.button_registruj_se));
        buttonRegistrujSe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        buttonPrijaviSeKaoGost = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.button_prijavi_se_kao_gost));
        buttonPrijaviSeKaoGost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginGostActivity.class);
                startActivity(i2);
            }
        });

        buttonPrijavaRegistrovaniKorisnik = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.button_prijava_registrovani_korisnik));
        buttonPrijavaRegistrovaniKorisnik.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i3);
            }
        });

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.connectWithFbButton);

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                info.setText(
                        "User ID: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                                + "\n" +
                                "Auth Token: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                );
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                info.setText("Login attempt canceled.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
            }
        });    
    }    

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }    

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {   
    }
}
```

Layout Code

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/connectWithFbButton"
    style="@style/com_facebook_loginview_default_style"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="43dp" />
```

Update: after i deleted duplicate code in MainActivity i'm still receiving the same errors when trying to ran app. I'm attaching Manifest code also as requested so maybe that would help? Thanx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<permission
    android:name="com.android.vlada.sportisa.Entiteti.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vlada.sportisa.Entiteti.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyAVb2JuN-5nbaVkGODivuXPJOF5OeRekzo" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/facebook_login" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegistrationActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".BiranjeAktivnosti" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Trazim"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_trazim"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Organizujem"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_organizujem"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
</application>
```

Comment: Sorry if i not posted correctly, this is my first question posted here. Tell me please if you need any other additional code from my project, and i will post it here immediately.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: why you 3 times use this code setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: and same do not init call 2 times  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

Comment: Thanx, i deleted those duplicates, but still receiving same errors.

Comment: update question and add manifest file in question.

Comment: Added Manifest code.

Comment: If you read your error's full trace you'll find it says "Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null or empty" and that is because your metadata tags are not available to your application. Try moving them inside your application tag in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Add metadata inside application tag before activities.
What you have now is:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyAVb2JuN-5nbaVkGODivuXPJOF5OeRekzo" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/facebook_login" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

Move metadata inside application tag like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAVb2JuN-5nbaVkGODivuXPJOF5OeRekzo" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_login" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this code in manifest file.

You also need to add the application id like this:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
  ...
  <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"  android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
  ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't what, but there's an issue with either `FacebookActivity` name or the support for `Gradle Version 2.3.0` is removed. I faced the same issue and with the following I got rid of this.

Replaced `<activity>` tag

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

with the `<meta>` tag.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/fb_id" />
```

---

**EDIT**

Also, I have placed this `<meta>` tag at the bottom of the file below, all the activities, above the closing tag.